# How to read files from anywhere with vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to read files from my music directory on my PC.
I have tried doing it with the node.js file system module, but it is not working. How do I get it to work?

Comment: Vue is a frontend framework. You cant read filesystems with that. The backend should take care of that (like PHP/Node/C#/...). You can make such data available using an API which Vue can call using AJAX requests.

Comment: I don't have a backend for the app

Comment: is there no library for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a late follow-up. It is possible to read and write files using HTML5 with the FileReader and saveAs(). The browser will open a file dialogue and let the user choose the file, so the user is aware of the file access. It is not possible to read or write to a file without the user's attention.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: This page from web.dev is helpful : https://web.dev/file-system-access/#how-to-use 
With a demo editor : https://googlechromelabs.github.io/text-editor/

Comment: Thank you for posting the link to the FileReader.  It took me to the FIleLIst documentation that included the "multiple" input option that now allows me to list and import several local files with one click...HTML5 Rocks!

Answer (score 0):

As said by @flame in a comment, it's just impossible, because the browser never have access to the visitor's disk (do you imagine the security issue if it was the case ?).

Vue.js is a Front-end framework, so the application it produces only have access to what the browser has access to.

Comment: Ok. I'll just find another approach to the problem. I'll write an API for it then.